# Wagtail admin: Linking to tabbed section via language formatted id

Tags: django, wagtail

I want to be able to go to a certain tab in the admin interface, but Im unsure how to go about it since Its language specific. I have this in my tabbed interface:

```
edit_handler = TabbedInterface(
    [
        ObjectList(content_panels, heading=_("Content")),
        ObjectList(form_content_panels, heading=_("Forms")),
        ObjectList(event_registration_panels, heading=_("Participants")),
        ObjectList(message_panels, heading=_("Messages")),
        ObjectList(promote_panels, heading=_("Promote")),
        ObjectList(TranslatablePage.settings_panels, heading=_("Settings")),
    ]
)
```

I now want to link directly to the messages tab for example. But the id for this is based on the gettext formatted heading, in swedish:

```
<section id="tab-meddelanden" class=" ">
```

in english:

```
<section id="tab-messages" class=" ">
```

This makes it hard to link correctly. How can I supply a non-language formatted id?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, Im a bit slow.

Of course, when creating the link I can use the same wording as when i create the heading, this creates the correct link.

```
tab_index_name = _("Participant").lower()
```